# Webdriverio, Android: How to write xpath properly using layout inspector?

Tags: android, android-studio, appium, webdriver-io, ui-testing

I'm no familiar with android app developing and testing.

However, I find myself that I'm only using resource-id when I need to find elements. But some elements doesn't have resource-id. So my thoughts was to use XPath to find elements.

How xpath would looks like for element TextInputEditText if parent element have id: card_name_input?

[layout inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0WMY.png)

Something like this?

```
//*[@resource-id="card_name_input"]//???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout Inspector in Android Studio is not showing actual classes and widgets, so can't be used for building xpath.

`uiautomatorviewer` and `monitor` provided with Java SDK seems like deprecated, I had a difficulties with running them.

Last thing is Appium ui inspector which show me correct xpath for element.